# Container for Android application : ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have started Android development recently. 
My ambition is to create an application which send an http request to get a list of posts.
For each post (in json), there is a name, a date and the content of the post.

I know how to parse a json file and how to fill objects.

I am curious about what kind of containers I should use. Is a ListView a nice choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the layout structure or some other details you need. I mean maybe your images are located in two or three columns or something like that. Otherwise of course you need to use ListView.

See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews